# What are capable hosting options for a cross-platform web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, cross-platform, web-hosting

I am a beginner currently writing a web application using ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio. This application will be accessed by users on their personal laptops or tablets- which will either be running a Mac or Windows OS.

I need this application to therefore be cross-platform (in its accessibility, not development) for OS.

I have done considerable research, but it's not clear to me how to best host the web app in a way that can be used by both Windows and Mac users. Microsoft Azure provides a seamless hosting opportunity especially for ASP.NET web apps, but the website on this page (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/) says it only supports Windows and Linux (Preview).

What are other ways to host the web app that will satisfy the above criteria? Does the ASP.NET framework version make a difference?

I will also need hosting for the back-end SQL server database, but that obviously doesn't have the same limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a web app on azure to host your asp.net MVC application. This application will run properly on Windows, MAC and Linux. It doesnt matter what the OS you are using here, what matters is the browser you are using whether Safari, Chrome, Mozilla. These browsers are available for install on all OS.

Comment: Thanks. So when a hosting company/service (such as Azure) says they "support Windows" they mean in terms of the OS the application was developed on, not run on? I just want to make sure I commit to the right approach.

Comment: They support Windows as server OS. Its up to you to develop apps and choose to support the client OS your clients use. You are mixing server technologies with client technologies in your thinking. Dont mix )

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification!